# How can I integrate someone well into my project?

Tags: unity, project-management, teamwork

I am working alone, since over one year on a decent sized project... to speed up things i wanted to incorporate some friends into development, unfortunately i never  did something like this before and so i dont know where to start.

What is important to work as a team ? What should he know, see and understand ? And what shouldnt he be aware of ? And most important, how would you integrate someone into your project ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. BUT there are some important issues hidden in here. Try to break it up into some seperate questions about specific aspects of the overall problem! :)

Comment: I agree 100% with @Almo - too broad, but great potential. If the scope can be narrowed enough to be brought on-topic, this is likely to be useful to many. One thing that might help is to focus on one role (coding, etc). For instance, here's a some what related question focusing on [art consistency](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50093/33287).